# Meteor Connection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to connect my app with mongodb. Adding a post with static array data works fine.

Problem: Nothing shows now up under {{post}}. If I check my DB, there is already data inserted.

Database Insert + Code:

```
db.calposts.insert({ post: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

{{#each calposts}}
  {{> posts}}
{{/each}}

<template name="posts">
<div class="panel-post" id="post-draggable">
    <span>{{post}}</span>
</div>
</template>

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.calendar.helpers({
    calposts: function () {
     return CalPosts.find({});
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: you're finding `CalPosts` but you're inserting into `db.calposts`? Should be `CalPosts.insert()`

Comment: db.calposts.insert .. was the mongo shell command to add data. It refers to CalPosts = new Meteor.Collection('calposts');

Answer (score 0):

Did you publish calpost collection to the client? 
If not, in the server folder somewhere you need to use `Meteor.publish()` and then on the client side, run `Meteor.subscribe()` to subscribe to the publication.

Check out this page on meteor.com for more info on publishing and subscribing:

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe

Comment: Thank you. Yes I added
    Meteor.subscribe("calposts");
        Template.calendar.helpers({
       calposts: function () {
        return CalPosts.find({});
      }
    });

and to server

     eteor.publish("calposts", function () {
       return CalPosts.find();
       });

But still no results..

Comment: Are you getting any meteor errors along with the data not showing up?